# Why does && sometimes bind lvalues and other times not?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, lvalue, rvalue

Ok I have this code:

```
struct Mine{
    template<typename T>
    Mine(T&& x){
    }
};
void nFoo(int&& x){
}
void sFoo(Mine x){
}
```

The `nFoo` takes an `int&&` directly, while the `sFoo` does some finagling to get the same effect.

Consider this code:

```
nFoo(12); //Works

int x = 0;
nFoo(x);  //Cannot bind int (lvalue) to int&&

sFoo(12); //Works
sFoo(x);  //Works
```

Why does the `int&&` sometimes allow binding from `lvalue`s and sometimes not?

Comment: Theres a nice article specifically on this in *Effective Modern C++* by Scott Meyers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why "universal references" have the same syntax as rvalue references?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364297/why-universal-references-have-the-same-syntax-as-rvalue-references)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why does the int&& sometimes allow binding from lvalues and sometimes not?

`int&&` doesn't bind to an lvalue because it is an *rvalue reference*.

`T&&`, in a context where `T` is a template argument, does bind to an lvalue because it is a [*forwarding reference*](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4164.pdf). It is not an rvalue reference, even though the syntax is nearly the same.

Comment: is there any source which you can advice to learn lvalue, rvalue, forwarding reference etc. blow-by-blow?

Comment: @snr I would imagine that modern C++ text books explain it all in a structured manner. The only C++ book that I own was written pre-c++11, so I don't know any that I can recommend. The document that I've now linked in the answer should describe forwarding references and their relation to the other references quite well.